# Remove Rows of Dataframe (Present in Both Columns)

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove from my dataframe rows that have present in two particular columns the same string value, I know that it is possible to remove a row if it has a particular string in the row with:

```
abs_pres_matrix[!grepl("BGC", abs_pres_matrix$Genome),]
```

In this case I have a dataframe such as:

```
  GC1      |   GC2    | Distance
BGC123       BGC23      0.5
BGC123       MBT_13     0.6
BGC134       MBT_13     0.5
BGC123       BGC 134    0.6
```

Desired Output:

```
  GC1      |   GC2    | Distance
BGC123       MBT_13     0.6
BGC134       MBT_13     0.5
```

Hence, I want to remove the columns that both contain the string "BGC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(  
     GC1 = c("BGC123","BGC123","BGC134","BGC123"), 
     GC2 = c("BGC123","MBT_13","MBT_13","BGC123"),  
     Distance = c(0.5, 0.6,  0.5, 0.6),  
     stringsAsFactors = F
    )
```

if you just want to delete the rows with "BGC", just go for grepl:

```
df[!grepl("BGC", df$GC2) , ]
#or
subset(df, !grepl("BGC", df$GC2))
```

if you want to eliminate the rows where GC1 is exactly like GC2 you can use subset with apply:

```
subset(df, apply(df, 1, function(x) x[1] %in% x[2]) )
```

Comment: this comand using the function subset `subset(mix_network, apply(mix_network, 1, function(x) x[1] %in% x[2]) )` will actually create a dataframe where these columns are exactly alike

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`.

```
abs_pres_matrix[!lengths(apply(abs_pres_matrix[, 1:2], 1, grep, pattern="BGC")) > 1,]
#      GC1    GC2 Distance
# 2 BGC123 MBT_13      0.6
# 3 BGC134 MBT_13      0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses three methods: (i) the rows are pasted into strings using `apply`and `paste0`; (ii) the strings are searched for the repeated occurrence of the pattern `BGC` using regex including backreference (`\\1`); (iii) those rows that satisfy this condition are removed from the dataframe using `-which`(or, alternatively, just `!`):

```
df[-which(grepl("(BGC).*\\1", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
     GC1    GC2 Distance
2 BGC123 MBT_13      0.6
3 BGC134 MBT_13      0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("GC")), all_vars(grepl("BGC", .)))
```